# How to access low definition videos of my own through Vimeo API?

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

I would like to access my own videos through Vimeo API and to download low and high definition versions that Vimeo encoded.
I have a Premium account on Vimeo.

I didn't find it in their doc :(
Is there a way? I would like to avoid encoding videos myself in different sizes...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First off, you'll need to be a Vimeo PRO member to get the direct video file URLs.

Using the latest API, do an authenticated `GET https://api.vimeo.com/videos/[clip_id]`. In the response you'll see an attribute named `files` that contain the HD, SD, and mobile transcodes that Vimeo generates. These URLs are meant for use with other video players (JWPlayer, or simply with the `<video>` tag, for example).

If you want to get the URLs to use for downloading (providing a download link on your site, for example) do the same authenticated `GET https://api.vimeo.com/videos/[clip_id]` to find the `download` attribute in the response. These URLs expire, and with them you'll see an `expires` attribute with the date and time.

Note that to get the download URLs, not only must you be authenticated as the clip owner, the API app itself must also be created by the clip owner.